# Generar tarea automática desde php

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un módulo que tiene como finalidad generar el envío de correos electrónicos, para ello dentro del formulario estoy pidiendo datos tales como, hora de alerta, fecha de inicio de la alerta, destinatarios del correo, frecuencia de la alerta, entre otros.

Mi pregunta es ... ¿es posible desde php generar un cron parametrizado con los datos que llegan del formulario?.

Comment: Es posible, aunque influirá, y mucho, la configuración del sistema, sobre todo permisos del usuario web para ejecutar y registrar tareas de cron. Otra opción es que crees un cron genérico que consulte un script en tu aplicación cada minuto (por ejemplo) y este sea el encargado de consultar si hay tareas para la hora y fecha actual y ejecutarlas si fuera necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu pregunta directamente la respuesta seria no, pero, lo que si puedes hacer es hacer un cron a un archivo php, que te consulte la información que guardaste del formulario, dentro del archivo haces las validaciones pertinentes que definiste en el formulario.

Si no quieres que este constantemente consultando la base de datos, podrías guardar el registro del formulario en un archivo JSON.

Comment: Tomando en cuenta tu respuesta, tengo una nueva duda. ¿Cómo hacer el llamado al archivo php desde un cron? He intentado con 5 * * * * wget http://direccionip/rutaArchivoPHP o 5 * * * * curl /www/var/html/proyecto/arcivho y tampoco lo he logrado

Comment: Pregunta: lo haces desde un vps, un servidor linux, windows, o un hosting?

Comment: Un servidor linux

Comment: @Andrés une las respuestas

Comment: para información puedes ver https://geekytheory.com/programar-tareas-en-linux-usando-crontab

En vez de wget, tienes que usar es php ejemplo:

***** php - f /bin/ejecutar/archivo.php